# Validar que una fecha no sea menor a otra en un trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

En la tabla empleado, si el usuario ingresa `fechaDefuncion`, el sistema debe validar *(con triggers)* que esta sea mayor a `fechaNacimiento`.

Soy bastante novato en esto, pero lo intento.  Tengo algo así de ese trigger hasta ahora:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER defuncionCheck BEFORE INSERT ON empleado
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
           IF fechaDefuncion > fechaNacimiento THEN
               INSERT INTO mistickets.empleado VALUES ( //aquí es lo que me falta
           ELSEIF fechaDefuncion <= fechaNacimiento THEN
               "ERROR! La fecha de defunción no puede ser menor o igual a la fecha de nacimiento";
           END IF;
       END;//
```

1. Está correcta la estructura en general del trigger?
2. Cómo queda el resto de la sentencia INSERT INTO para que me almacene la fecha insertada en el campo `fechaDefuncion` ?

[image: Pantallazo de mi la estructura de la tabla Empleado]

Comment: Hola @RafaelOrtiz, no era necesario eliminar la pregunta anterior, puedes modificar una pregunta las veces que sean necesarias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te propongo algo así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER defuncionCheck
  BEFORE INSERT ON empleado FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF new.fechaDefuncion < new.fechaNacimiento THEN
      set new.fechaDefuncion=NULL;
    END IF;
  END;
```

Para este dataset simplificado:

```
CREATE TABLE empleado(
  idEmpleado int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombreEmpleado varchar(31),
  fechaNacimiento date,
  fechaDefuncion date
  );
```

Puedes probar con:

```
INSERT INTO empleado (nombreEmpleado, fechaNacimiento, fechaDefuncion) VALUES
  ('e1','2020-05-03','2020-05-02'),
  ('e2','2020-05-03','2020-05-03'),
  ('e3','2020-05-03','2020-05-04');
```

De forma que obtendrás:

> ```
> 1 1   e1  03/05/2020  (null)
> 2 2   e2  03/05/2020  03/05/2020
> 3 3   e3  03/05/2020  04/05/2020
> ```

La idea es que, en vez dar un error, te deja insertar el dato, pero con la fecha de defunción a `NULL` de forma que posteriormente puedas localizar los registros erróneos con:

```
SELECT * FROM empleado
  WHERE fechaDefuncion IS NULL;
```

Aunque realmente el disparador no tiene mucho sentido pues, con esta consulta, ya podrías localizar los registros erróneos para requerir su subsanación:

```
SELECT * FROM empleado
  WHERE fechaDefuncion<fechaNacimiento;
```

Comment: Interesante solución David, gracias

Comment: Gracias a ti por elegirla, tengo que reconocer que la de @BetaM es más canónica. Con ésta gestionas el problema de otra forma, al final dependerá de cómo vayas a programar el resto de la aplicación que explote la base de datos. Con ésta guardas el resto de los datos del registro y, con la otra, rechazas el registro completo.

Answer (score 2):

El trigger deberá verificar lo siguiente:

- Si el valor new de la fecha de defunción es menor al valor new de la fecha de nacimiento deberás lanzar un mensaje de error
- Como estás comprobando valores que aún no existen en tu tabla y que apenas se insertarán deben ir los nombre de las columnas con el prefijo `NEW`
- Puedes manejar el estado de error por medio de `signal sqlstate`
- El trigger lo debes programar con la indicación de `BEFORE INSERT` para que se ejecute justo antes de que el registro sea almacenado comprobando los valores que apenas vas a mandar a almacenar

> No es necesario que establezcas el insert into dentro del condicional de tu trigger, solo es necesario que valides las fechas, en caso de que la fecha de defunción sea menor lanzará el mensaje de error y en caso contrario la acción continuará y se procesará el insert.

Código:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER validaFecha BEFORE INSERT ON tuTabla
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF(New.fechaDefuncion < New.fechaNacimiento) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'La fecha de defunción no puede ser menor a la fecha de nacimiento';
END IF;
END; //
```

**REFERENCIAS**

- [SIGNAL SQLSTATE en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html)
- [Sintaxis de triggers en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)